# I can't find the function that is pointed out in the compiler

Tags: c, linux, codeblocks, raspberry-pi3

I work on openvg library. Actually I worked for run this code with Code Blocks(on raspberry): https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/blob/master/opt/vc/src/hello_pi/hello_font/main.c

I achieved render color and I saw aliasing. But I want write text on screen with use same method. I analyzed this library: https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/blob/master/opt/vc/src/hello_pi/libs/vgfont/vgfont.h and tried use `graphics_resource_render_text_ext()` function but I took this message on a new terminal window:

> assertion failure:font.c:176:gx_priv_render_text():inited aborted

My compile build message this:
[image]

Font.c's path: https://github.com/adafruit/rpi-firmware/blob/master/vc/sdk/opt/vc/src/hello_pi/libs/vgfont/font.c.

I went 176. line on font.c and tried call `gx_font_init()`(terminal window remark this line.) but I couldn't found this function anywhere(I tried find in raspberry's). If I cancel `graphics_resource_render_text_ext()` command, my code is good work. Why can't I use this function?  My code this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include "bcm_host.h"
#include "vgfont.h"
#include "openvg.h"
#include "egl.h"
#include "vgu.h"
#include "fontinfo.h"
#include "shapes.h"
#include "eglplatform.h"
#include "graphics_x_private.h"

int main()
{       
    GRAPHICS_RESOURCE_HANDLE img;
    uint32_t width, height;
    int LAYER = 1;
    bcm_host_init();

    int s;

    s = gx_graphics_init(".");
    assert(s == 0);
    s = graphics_get_display_size(0, &width, &height);
    assert(s == 0);
    s = gx_create_window(0, width, height, GRAPHICS_RESOURCE_RGBA32, &img);
    assert(s == 0);

    graphics_resource_fill(img, 0, 0, width, height, GRAPHICS_RGBA32(0, 0, 0, 0x00));
    graphics_display_resource(img, 0, LAYER, 0, 0, GRAPHICS_RESOURCE_WIDTH, GRAPHICS_RESOURCE_HEIGHT, VC_DISPMAN_ROT0, 1 );

    while(1)
    {
        graphics_resource_fill(img, 0, 0,width, height, GRAPHICS_RGBA32(0,0,0,0x55));
        graphics_resource_fill(img, 600, 500, 100, 50, GRAPHICS_RGBA32(0,0,0xff,0xaa));
        graphics_resource_fill(img, 600, 400, 200, 50, GRAPHICS_RGBA32(0,0xff,0,0xaa));

        graphics_resource_render_text_ext( img, 100, 100, 200, 200, GRAPHICS_RGBA32(0xff,0,0,0xdd), GRAPHICS_RGBA32(0, 0xff,0, 0xdd), "hello", strlen("hello"), 20);  // This line has problem.

        graphics_update_displayed_resource(img, 0,0,0,0);
    }

    graphics_display_resource(img, 0, LAYER, 0, 0, GRAPHICS_RESOURCE_WIDTH, GRAPHICS_RESOURCE_HEIGHT, VC_DISPMAN_ROT0, 0); 
    graphics_delete_resource(img);

    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**NOTE:** did not changed compiler build message when I cancelled `graphics_resource_render_text_ext()` but code worked good.

Comment: `gx_priv_font` doesn't exist, the comment in the source code is wrong. Actual function that gets called is `gx_priv_font_init` (it *should* be called when you call `gx_graphics_init`, but something fails during the init. I've added more details below. Are you sure that the path `.` is correct when calling `gx_graphics_init(".")`? Perhaps the resources are in a different folder? It's also strange that `assert(s == 0);` doesn't fail, because `gx_graphics_init` should return an error.

Comment: @Groo How can I check `.` path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [source code](https://github.com/adafruit/rpi-firmware/blob/master/vc/sdk/opt/vc/src/hello_pi/libs/vgfont/font.c#L157) for `gx_priv_render_text` it appears that the assertion fails because the `inited` static variable is not set.

This variable is set through `gx_graphics_init` (it's [here inside `graphics.c`](https://github.com/adafruit/rpi-firmware/blob/8f305cad54cf725a14551b59a2e33c6fd37d7492/vc/sdk/opt/vc/src/hello_pi/libs/vgfont/graphics.c#L972)), which calls `gx_priv_font_init` if the initialization succeeds.

So, the initialization fails somewhere inside `gx_priv_initialise`. Set a breakpoint there and go step by step through the function, and check the log also (it should contain one of the error messages found inside that function).

Comment: So why inited neccessery? What is mission of it?

Comment: I set breakpoint my code but error on program console this : GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Operation not permitted.

Comment: @F.Kılavuz: the function `gx_priv_initialise` initializes this graphics library and sets `inited` to `1` if everything goes ok. So, this is basically telling you that something went wrong. You should enable logging, go into the [`graphics_x_private.h`](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/blob/469f2d8eb88a4ef71f77d4912b8f15ba3a7dd57b/opt/vc/src/hello_pi/libs/vgfont/graphics_x_private.h#L47) file and remove those `if`s in the `GX_LOG` defines, i.e. just write `#define GX_LOG(format, arg...) printf( format "\n", ##arg)`.

Comment: I did it but this time I gave Could not open font file 'Vera.ttf' error.

Comment: Vera.ttf path is `/opt/vc/src/hello_pi/hello_font/Vera.ttf`. I write this `gx_graphics_init("c:\\opt \\vc\\src\\hello_pi\\hello_font\\Vera.ttf")` but result is same. Also `Vera.ttf` file is empty.

Comment: If this is linux then just write `/opt/vc/src/hello_pi/hello_font`, no filename at the end, just the folder. It's weird that the file is empty though, [it's ~64kB on Github](https://github.com/adafruit/rpi-firmware/raw/8f305cad54cf725a14551b59a2e33c6fd37d7492/vc/sdk/opt/vc/src/hello_pi/hello_font/Vera.ttf) -- perhaps this was the problem from the beginning, so try if the `"."` path will work after you download the correct file.

Comment: Also I want added this: If you want use `"."`,  you must bring `.ttf` file where opened you project. Because `"."` works here for find `.ttf` file.